# Which one of these 2 "where clauses" perform better, and why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-performance

Well, the question is crystal clear. Here is the first query:

```
SELECT
    o.Col1,
    o.Col2
FROM
    [Orders] o
WHERE
    ISNULL(@CustomerId, o.CustomerId) = o.CustomerId
```

And here is the other one:

```
SELECT
    o.Col1,
    o.Col2
FROM
    [Orders] o
WHERE
    CASE
        WHEN @CustomerId IS NULL THEN 1
        ELSE IIF(@CustomerId = o.CustomerId, 1, 0)
    END = 1
```

Thank you.

Comment: They should both be equally bad, because neither is sargable.

Comment: Read [Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html) by Erland Sommarskog. He explains several approaches in details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to write it would be:

```
SELECT
    o.Col1,
    o.Col2
FROM
    [Orders] o
WHERE
    @CustomerId IS NULL OR @CustomerId = o.CustomerId
```

At least the query optimizer can see ahead if `@CustomerId` is null or not and pick a plan accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you care about performance, then you can use dynamic SQL or a query like this:

```
SELECT o.Col1, o.Col2
FROM Orders o
WHERE @CustomerId is null 
UNION ALL
SELECT o.Col1, o.Col2
FROM Orders o
WHERE o.CustomerId = @CustomerId;
```

The first subquery won't use an index but should detect if no values are being returned.  The second only returns a value when the customer ids match, and can use an index.

```
ISNULL(@CustomerId, o.CustomerId) = o.CustomerId
```